# "Error 404 Not Found" in Magento Admin Login Page

Tags: php, magento

I just transfered my magento installation from one local machine server to another. Now, I cannot login to admin panel. When I go to the admin login url, I get the following error message:-

**"Error: 404 Not Found"**

Some of my module's pages also show this error.

Can anyone please figure out the problem?

Comment: This type of question doesn't really belong on Stack Overflow, as it's not a programming question. You should take a look at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/25439/magento and see about getting a proper place to put these kind of questions

Comment: Yes, this is a programming question.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution to my problem.

I looked into the Magento system log file (var/log/system.log). There I saw the exact error.

The error is as below:-

> Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed
>   to Mage_Core_Model_Store::setWebsite()
>   must be an instance of
>   Mage_Core_Model_Website, null given,
>   called in
>   YOUR_PATH\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php
>   on line 555 and defined in
>   YOUR_PATH\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Store.php
>   on line 285
>
> Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed
>   to
>   Mage_Core_Model_Store_Group::setWebsite()
>   must be an instance of
>   Mage_Core_Model_Website, null given,
>   called in
>   YOUR_PATH\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php
>   on line 575 and defined in
>   YOUR_PATH\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Store\Group.php
>   on line 227

Actually, I had this error before. But, error display message like `Error: 404 Not Found` was new to me.

The reason for this error is that `store_id` and `website_id` for admin should be set to **0 (zero)**. But, when you import database to new server, somehow these values are not set to 0.

Open PhpMyAdmin and run the following query in your database:-

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `core_store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `core_store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `core_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

I have written about this problem and solution over here:-

[**Magento: Solution to "Error: 404 Not Found" in Admin Login Page**](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-solution-to-error-404-not-found-in-admin-login-page/)

Comment: _But, when you import database to new server, somehow these values are not set to 0._. This is not true I have moved magento several time and these values never changed.

Comment: It was transferring Magento from one local machine server to another.. I also hadn't got such error in other instances but in this case I got such error..

Comment: When you use Magento's backup tool it will add this line to the sql output: 
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
This might be missing when you use any other method exporting the database causing mysql to start importing at 1 when it really should use 0 as ID.

Comment: @Fooman: Ya.. you may be right.

Comment: work for me as well. Thank you so much for saving my day.

Comment: My Magento database doesn't have these tables...?

Comment: My solution was just to follow this http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/restoring_a_backup_of_a_magento_database and add those magical SQL at the beginning and at the end. (thx Fooman)

Comment: Thank you soooo much! That saved me A LOT of time!

Comment: Hmm, it works! Thank you.

Comment: @MukeshChapagain thanks man I wasted a day behind this same non working solutions everywhere. @ShaktiSingh actually this happens when you use `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;` at the top of sql file while importing database. atleast this happened in my case.

Answer (score 4):

I have just copied and moved a Magento site to a local area so I could work on it offline and had the same problem.

But in the end I found out Magento was forcing a redirect from http to https and I didn't have a SSL setup. So this solved my problem http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/recover/ssl_access_with_phpmyadmin

It pretty much says set web/secure/use_in_adminhtml value from 1 to 0 in the core_config_data to allow non-secure access to the admin area

Answer (score -3):

Thanks to all, for me this solution worked:
[Magento 404 page in backoffice after login](http://www.johanvandepol.nl/2010/06/magento-404-page-in-backoffice-after-login/)

Comment: Interestingly enough, this URL 404s. It's usually best to post an answer, not a link (in case the link goes away)