# Magento 1.9.1 admin 404 error, after transfer

Tags: magento

I transfered my magento. Now, I cannot login to admin panel.

What i do

1) change old url to new in MySQL

2) delete var/cache

3) try login via /index.php/admin

4) change local.xml

5) this issue don`t work too ["Error 404 Not Found" in Magento Admin Login Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178066/error-404-not-found-in-magento-admin-login-page)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic, better suited for http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: sorry, i don`t know about this

Comment: Please check admin url in local.xml

Comment: solution. 
Delete sessions folder var/sessions
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/32922/magento-1-9-0-1-admin-404-error-after-transfer?noredirect=1#comment44582_32922