# Magento Admin Panel not found (404)

Tags: magento

Can't open Admin Panel at Magento: "The page you requested was not found. But, we're on it..." :(

Logs are:

```
2015-08-09T08:41:49+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: catalog.topnav  in /home2/shoptell/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 460
2015-08-09T08:41:50+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: nothumbnail  in/home2/shoptell/public_html/app/code/local/Cmsmart/Megamenu/Block/Navigation.php on line 95
2015-08-09T08:41:50+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: nothumbnail  in /home2/shoptell/public_html/app/code/local/Cmsmart/Megamenu/Block/Navigation.php on line 95
```

And other "Undefined variable" errors.
Tried (but what for?) to make a SQL request as described at ["Error 404 Not Found" in Magento Admin Login Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178066/error-404-not-found-in-magento-admin-login-page) but same no result. Same as clean var/cache.
Main page is working. Only Admin Panel.

Does anybody can help with that problem? Don't know how correct solve problems of **undefined index** in logs.

(besides, try to add maintance.flag into root - site all the same is available)

Comment: have you tried resetting the file permissions?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried resetting the file permissions?

from the command line try running:

```
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; && sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; && sudo chmod o+w var var/.htaccess app/etc && sudo chmod 550 mage && sudo chmod -R o+w media && sudo chmod -R 777 var/ media/
```