# Magento admin URL changed

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, phpmyadmin, magento-2.0

I am trying to access my magento admin panel, but I am getting the error 404, I think the admin URL has been changed from the admin panel by another admin user.
Is there anyway where I can change the URL or get access to the admin panel.

Note:I wanted to change the URL through the local.xml file, but I don't have a local.xml configuration file in the directory.

Thanks

[magento admin apanel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1Y4o.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

In **Magento 1x**

try this query and check your url is correct or not.

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE "%admin/url/%";
```

and remove all cache from cache folder.

check these links too

["Error 404 Not Found" in Magento Admin Login Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178066/error-404-not-found-in-magento-admin-login-page)

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73228/where-is-admin-url-custom-path-in-magento-site-database-file

**To change the Magento Admin URL / Path**

open the local.xml configuration file ,is usually located in the

> app/etc/

directory under your Magento installation.Then locate the following code segment:

```
 <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
```

replace **admin** with your new admin path.

Then Use an FTP client to delete the content of the var/cache/ directory.

**Magento 2**

***Change Admin Path***

It is not recommended to change it directly from app/etc/env.php, always prefer the CLI:

```
php bin/magento setup:config:set --backend-frontname="admin_path"
```

Do not add the first / in the admin_path as it will result in an invalid parameter exception.

***Change Admin URL***

This can be done via the admin under Store > Advanced Tab > Admin Base URL section

Comment: Recently I got to know that the Magento 2 uses env.php file for as configuration file.

Comment: Everything is perfect here in env.php file, it means there 404 error is due to some other issues.

Comment: did you find the solution?