# 404 Not Found error While Login into the magento Ves Bakerop theme

Tags: php, mysql, magento, xampp, http-status-code-404

**Error for Below**

Whoops, our bad...

The page you requested was not found, and we have a fine guess why.

- If you typed the URL directly, please make sure the spelling is correct.
- If you clicked on a link to get here, the link is outdated.

What can you do?
    Have no fear, help is near! There are many ways you can get back on track with Magento Store.

- Go back to the previous page.
- Use the search bar at the top of the page to search for your products. Follow these links to get you back on track!
      Store Home | My Account

**And Image..**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeoJ8.png)

Comment: The error just means that there just is no such site as `admin_2017`

Comment: Your website is in magneto1 or magneto2 ?

Comment: Now I found that solution thanks a lot. here that solution link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178066/error-404-not-found-in-magento-admin-login-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an answer [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/110470) for Magento 2

You will find more answers [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Yes, But am find that solution. Thank you,  @PiyushMathur

Comment: Hope this answer might help others with the same issue.